# find matching values in a given set of lists

Tags: python, string, list

i am trying to write a code in python3.8 that will run on a set of lists that will look like that

```
[[[10:59],[11:02],[11:03]],[[10:03],[11:02]] ... ]
```

each list inside represents times when an attempted login happened for a user
list 1 for user 1 and so on..
i am trying to find a way to find login attempts that happend at the same time and make it work with any amount of users

```
 loginTimes = [**[['10:35:54', '10:35:56'], ['10:35:56', '10:35:58'], ['10:38:17', '10:38:18'], ['10:38:18', '10:38:19'], ['10:38:19', '10:38:19'], ['10:38:19', '10:38:20']]**, **[['10:38:19', '10:38:20'], ['10:39:19', '10:39:20']]**]

   for i in range(len(loginTimes)-1):
        for time_a in loginTimes[i]:
            for time_b in loginTimes[i+1]:
                if time_a == time_b:
                    print(time_a)
                    print(time_b)


>>> ['10:38:19', '10:38:20']
    ['10:38:19', '10:38:20']
```

this is what i got it only works with 2 diffrent users

Comment: why `['10:38:19', '10:38:20']` is considered as same time?

Comment: Your first line of code is not valid python. Make sure you post your code _as it is_, Formatting is not accepted inside code blocks.

Comment: Do you have a set of lists (as per your title and question body) or a list of lists (as per your example? Or can it be either?

Comment: Use ` for i in range(len(loginTimes)):` (without the `-1`) to loop over the whole list. Otherwise, you miss the last element (remember `range` already excludes the last value).

Comment: Each list at the lowest level in your code has two times, but in your description you said it should have one. If the lowest level is the user number, then what's the second level? Please clarify.